# Why is MVC 3 Validation overwriting mine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In my model I have a particular field that is annotated in the following manner:

```
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Text)]
    [RegularExpression("[0-9]{1,10}", ErrorMessage = "The stated Attempt Id is invalid!")]
    public long? AttemptId { get; set; }
```

When I enter incorrect data in the Attempt ID it is giving me the following error message in the Model State:

```
The value 'cbcbxcb' is not valid for AttemptId.
```

I have other field with similar error messages but they're of type string instead of long? and the correct error message is being displayed in those cases when an invalid value is given. Why isn't the message for the 'long?' being used? I'm displaying my errors using the folowing literal tag in the page.

```
<%: Html.TValidationSummary() %>
```

EDIT: I have attempted to change the validation in the model to the following:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="The stated Attempt Id is invalid!", AllowEmptyStrings=true)]
```

This however is still incorrect. Firstly, I need to allow the field to be left empty, and when I do it's giving me the 'The stated Attempt Id is invalid!' error message. Secondly when I do enter invalid data in the field it's reverting back to its old bad error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegularExpression validation attribute only works with string types. To get a custom error message, use the Required validation attribute instead and put your own custom error message in.

If your model parameter isn't mandatory, you could perform the validation within the controller and add your own custom message using the ModelState.AddModelError method - this is a bit of a hack, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. now the trick is that that particular field isn't really a required field so a user should be allowe dot keep it empty. Is there a way to do what you're suggesting without binding it as 'required'?

Comment: I changed the validation to '[Required(ErrorMessage="The stated Attempt Id is invalid!", AllowEmptyStrings=true)]' and now its displaying the error message if left empty (which it shouldn't) and still displaying its wrong error messag eif invalid.

Comment: Have edited to provide an alternative solution if your parameter is non-mandatory

Comment: I do have some validatin within the controller but how can I really valide if the value of a long? is actually a long? ? I mean if the model is being populated within the page then the problem is occuring before it gets to the controller

Comment: You can't. The data mapper within ASP.NET MVC will perform pre-checks to ensure that the data you're passing is of the correct type.

Comment: Ok but cna the error message be overridden? cause that's the only rela problem here. I do want him to perform the check, I just want him to use an error message I supply him with.

Comment: Not really, since you're trying to compare a horse with a car in data type terms.

Comment: I suppose you're right, I'm switching my data types to String and validating form there.

Answer (score 1):

its probably the fact that MVCs binding can't even cast the input value into the correct type, so it already knows the value must be invalid.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to have MVC use my message when this occurs?

Comment: haven't tried it, you could try this approach from another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173034/override-datatype-mismatch-message-of-property-in-asp-net-mvcand-display-messag

Answer (score 1):

You should be using FluentValidation

The built in validation stuff using attributes is brittle and nasty - to say the least.

Comment: Would love to use something that works, unfortunately this isn't a personal project and introducing a third party piece of software into the system isn't an option. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.